# Extract bits of a register starting with the most significant bit, or a high bit

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, nasm

EDIT:

I didn't expect this question to gain traction so quickly. Following from the answers I've already received it seems I may have left out an important piece of information. The pattern is **not a fixed amount of bits**. Some letters might have more or fewer bits. I.e, B has 5 bits, but C might use up to 6 bits, but none use more than a byte. I've included an example of the 'A' bit pattern in my question which uses 7 bits for each line. Also see edit at the bottom of the question.

I'm new to assembly. I have bit pattern which corresponds to a text representation of a letter. Each 1 represents a $ (or any symbol) and each 0 represents a blank space. I.e:

```
    $$$$            11110
    $   $           10001
    $   $           10001
    $$$$            11110
    $   $           10001
    $   $           10001
    $$$$            11110

   $            0001000  
  $ $           0010100
 $$$$$          0111110  
$     $         1000001
```

I've written an assembly language program which reads each pattern and prints the right symbol depending on if it reads a 1 or a 0. To determine if it is a 1 or a 0, I AND the register with 1 and then right shift the bits an amount of times equaling the amount of bits in each line and then compare the result:

Notice that the bits for each row are stored at the bottom of a separate 2-byte word, which I load into an 8-bit register.

```
patternb:   dw 011110b,010001b,010001b,011110b,010001b,010001b,011110b

rowloop:
    mov bl,[patternb+si]    ;iterate through each element in binary array

    patternloop:    
        mov bh,bl   ;move bit pattern into register so that we can change it
        and bh,1    ;AND register to find set bits and store back in register
        shr bl,1    ;SHIFT original bit pettern right
        cmp bh,1    ;check if bit is set or not (1=set, else 0)
        je writesym ;if set, write symbol
        jne writeblank  ;if not set, write space
```

The problem is the way that AND works. Obviously it starts from the least significant bit and prints as the bits are shifted right, but this causes the problem that it prints the letter in "reverse" order. I.e:

```
 ####
#   #
#   #
 ####
#   #
#   #
 ####
```

I've tried a few bit manipulations but none seem to work. I've also tried shifting and rotating the bit pattern to correspond to the correct printing but this won't work for each line as not each line needs to be manipulated in this way. (Line 2 for example will print correctly without needing to be manipulated first). I have this same bit pattern technique for each letter from A-E.

**Ideally I'd want it to start comparing from the most significant bit somehow which should then print it in the correct order**, but I'm not sure on how to go about manipulating the bits in order to achieve that.

EDIT:
Following Peter Duniho's answer, I'd like to post some things I have tried:
I've tried AND'ing the pattern with 10000b and then ROL the result to get an answer of `00001b` and then shift the bits left. Then compare the result to see which symbol should be printed. This doesn't work either but because the bit pattern isn't always fixed it wouldn't be a solution anyway.

```
    mov bh,bl   ;move bit pattern into register so that we can change it
    and bh,10000b ;AND register to find set bits and store back in register
    rol bh,1    ;rol result to obtain 00001b
    shl bl,1    ;SHIFT original bit pettern right
    cmp bh,1    ;check if bit is set or not (1=set, else 0)
    je writesym ;if set, write symbol
    jne writeblank  ;if not set, write space
```

The closest I've come right now to solving this problem (with some help from Peter Duniho's answer as guidance) is to store my bit array as full 8 bit form (i.e. `011110000b`, etc instead of `011110b` otherwise the assembler stores it as `00011101` implicitly as mentioned in Martin Rosenau's answer, which we don't want) AND it with the full `10000000b` (since we're using at most 8 bits and this lets us check the MSB) instead of the 1 (`000000001b`) as I was trying to do before and then using the ROL and compare approach above (Or just compare it to `10000000b`). The loop runs a total of 7 times (due to each letter having 7 lines/bit patterns, except A which has 4 so A does not print right, but this is a problem I can solve myself with some conditions. The program works and prints correctly now. This is the code I've used:

```
        mov bh,bl   ;move bit pattern into register so that we can change it
        and bh,10000000b   ;AND register to find set bits and store back in register
        rol bh,1    ;shift MSB to LSB to compare (or could just compare with 10000000b instead)
        shl bl,1    ;SHIFT original bit pettern left
        cmp bh,1    ;check if bit is set or not (or use cmp bh,10000000b and omit rol above)
        je writesym ;if set, write symbol
        jne writeblank  ;if not set, write space
```

I've marked Peter's solution as the answer as it was the one which pointed me in the right direction to solve this. But as he mentioned there are a great number of ways to solve this problem (as indicated by the differing solutions posted) but his just happened to be the easiest for me to implement for my own code which is what he was going for.

Martin Rosenau's answer was also insightful especially the optimizations. I'll try to implement those when I have some more time and then update the solution above.

Comment: shift left to shift a bit out the top, into CF.  e.g. `add bl,bl / jc writesym` / else fall through or `jmp` to writeblank.

Comment: re: edit: How does your code know where the bit pattern starts, if it's actually variable width?  It seems like it would be much easier to consider each block as always 8x7, even if the first couple columns are all zeros.  Then you can trivially decode it the way I suggested in my first comment, by shifting one bit at a time into CF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ideally I'd want it to start comparing from the most significant bit somehow which should then print it in the correct order

Seems like a fine idea to me. Did you try anything along those lines? If so, what specifically did you try? What specific difficulty did you have?

In the meantime…

What determines the number of bit positions to examines (i.e. the loop count)? Is it fixed? If so, why not just AND with the bit at the high end instead of the low end (e.g. `10000b`, aka `16`) and shift left instead of right?

E.g.

```
mov bh,bl     ;move bit pattern into register so that we can change it
and bh,10000b ;AND register to find set bits and store back in register
shl bl,1      ;SHIFT original bit pattern left
cmp bh,10000b ;check if bit is set or not (1=set, else 0)
je writesym   ;if set, write symbol
jne writeblank  ;if not set, write space
```

If you do not know the loop count until runtime, you can just shift for each iteration:

```
mov bh,bl     ;move bit pattern into register so that we can change it
shr bh,cl     ;the assumption being that cl has the width of your bit pattern
dec cl        ;next bit
and bh,1      ;AND register to find set bits and store back in register
cmp bh,1      ;check if bit is set or not (1=set, else 0)
je writesym   ;if set, write symbol
jne writeblank  ;if not set, write space
```

If you're already using CX for your loop, obviously the above would need to be modified a bit. But hopefully you get the basic idea.

A variation on the above would be to e.g. store the AND bit pattern in another register (e.g. `al`) by storing `1` and shifting left the appropriate count (e.g. `shl al,cl`), and then using `al` as the operand instead of `10000b` as in the first example above.

These are far from your only options. You would need to narrow the constraints of your question considerably to get a more specific answer. But, assuming this is an exercise to learn ASM, this is a great opportunity for you to read and learn more about the bit-manipulation operations available to you. :)

Comment: You should simplify the OP's code, like `shl bl,1` / `test bl, 1<<5 / jnz writesym`.  It doesn't need 2 registers or any copying, and definitely not a variable-count shift.  (If you have 386 instructions, you can handle variable count with `bt bx, cx` to set CF = the bit-position selected by CX.  Otherwise you could create a mask for `test` outside the loop.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, thank you for those additional points. Unfortunately, there are a great number of variations on this theme. I was hoping to not have to write an exhaustive enumeration of all variations, but rather post something that was very close to what the OP is already doing, to minimize potential confusion (i.e. here, pedagogical concerns override code efficiency, IMHO). But you are right...there are other, even better ways to perform these operations.

Comment: I would have just written one efficient example of each way, like Martin's answer.  No need to enumerate all the ways, or even try, but using only a couple instructions makes the example easier to understand for future readers, and a better example to copy.  I think that beginners capable of following program logic can fairly quickly see how their version was overcomplicated once they see it done in a simple way.  So I don't think removing inefficiency is an obstacle to understanding.  Besides, that's only one reader; everyone else probably isn't stuck in their copy-and-destroy strategy.

Comment: Stack Overflow answers should generally be good examples in every respect that future readers can learn from, or copy/paste without shooting themselves in the foot.  I strongly disagree with the practice of minimally changing the OP's inefficient way of doing things, when it's easy and when the efficient version is shorter and simpler with less going on.

Comment: @PeterCordes: you're welcome to your opinion. :) Tell you what: you post an answer that provides a good level of detail, as well as demonstrates _and explains_ the optimizations you are saying should be in an answer, and I will delete my answer and up-vote yours. That seems like a more productive use of your time than commenting on my answer.

Comment: Martin already posted an answer that's close enough to what I would have written.  He explains which operations are essential, and explains that `test` lets you non-destructively check a bit, or `shl` or `add same,same` will shift a bit into CF where you can test it with `jc` or `jnc`.  The optimization follows naturally from that.

Comment: Thanks you both for your inputs. It's interesting to see the different approaches to this. I've since updated my question with quite a lot more information. Peter Duniho's answer just happened to be the easier one to understand in order to solve my problem, but Peter Cordes does make a good point when it comes to the optimization which I will also try to implement. Please see my updated question. Again, thank you both.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is the way that AND works.

Your first problem is the way that a right shift works. A right shift would remove the rightmost "pixel" of your "image" and move the pixel left of that pixel into the rightmost position (so that pixel will be the next pixel to be printed):

```
"$$$ $ $ " ->
" $$$ $ $" ->
"  $$$ $ " ->
"   $$$ $" ->
...
```

If you want to print the pixels from left to right, you'll have to perform a **left shift**, not a right shift.

(Note that a left shift can be done using `shl bl,1` or using `add bl,bl`.)

Because your "image" is only 5 "pixels" wide but a byte has 8 bits, you'll have to decide if you add unused bits at the left side or the right side of your image.

e.g.:

```
"$$$ $" = 11101000 or 00011101 ?
```

Let's say you decided to add the pixels at the left side (00011101 - which the assembler will implicitly do if you specify the number as `011101b`).

Then you'll have to perform an `AND` operation with a value that has the bit representing the leftmost pixel set:

```
Old:              New:

and bh,1          and bh, 010000b
shr bl,1          shl bl, 1
```

---

By the way: There are two optimizations possible to your program:

**1) Use the fact that the leftmost bit is not lost:**

```
patternloop:    
    shl bl,1
    test bl,0100000b
    je writesym
```

This optimization uses the fact that there are 3 free bits in the byte, so the left bit of the byte is not "lost" in a left shift:

```
"0 0 0<1>1 1 0 1"
  -> Left shift ->
"0 0<1>1 1 0 1 0"

"< >" = Bit you are interested in
```

The instruction `test bl,xxx` affects the `ZF` flag (which affects the `je` instruction) the same way as the combination of the two instructions `and bl,xxx` followed by `cmp bl,0` but it does not modify the `bl` register!

**2) Use the fact that a right shift shifts out the bit to `CF`:**

```
patternloop:    
    shl bl,1
    jc writesym
```

This optimization assumes that "$$$ $" is stored as 11101000 and not as 00011101. It uses the fact that `shl` will copy the leftmost (highest) bit to the `CF` flag before doing the shift (assuming a shift by 1 bit is done):

```
BL="<1>1 1 0 1 0 0 0", CF=?
   -> Left shift (using SHL or ADD) ->
BL="1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0", CF=<1>
```

The `jc` instruction will perform a jump if the `CF` flag is set.

Comment: Was about to post something similar using `add` / `test`.  Just had the idea that `shl bl, 3` *before* the loop will bring the bits of interest to the top and set up for an `add bl,bl` / `jc` loop, saving the `test bl, 1<<5`.

Comment: *shl will copy the leftmost (highest) bit to the CF flag before doing the shift:*  That's only true for shift by 1, and could be confusing for `shl bl, 2`.  I think it's easier to understand the way Intel describes it, as CF as getting the last bit shifted out.  (Or of course using `add bl,bl` makes it an actual carry from a normal add, and is more efficient because it can macro-fuse with a `jc` on modern CPUs.)

Comment: @MartinRosenau: I think he means the line where you wrote `010000h` (hex, not binary).  But since NASM supports expressions, IMO it's much easier to write `test bl, 1<<5` to write the bit-position in the source instead of making readers count.  or `1<<(5+1)` after a shift.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes. This should be a "b" not a "h". I corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opcode `ROL` which rotates bits toward MSB by one and the MSB would be rotated to the location of LSB, eg :

11110000 -> ROL 1 -> 11100001

So that you can do something like :

ROL1 -> test LSB -> ROL1 -> test LSB -> ....

In your case, bl is an 8-bits regitser, loop the ROL, test 8 times to draw the ascii art

Comment: This does not work with the sample data given, i.e. where there's only 5 significant bits.

Comment: You are trying to help someone who is clearly inexperienced with bit manipulation, if not assembly in general. It behooves you to make sure your answer does not omit particulars like "just ignore the first three ROL". It's very much a big deal to someone who wouldn't naturally infer that all on their own.